# golang can't reflect to map[interface{}]interface{}

Tags: json, go

My original problem is I want to parse [URL.Values](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values) to a generic type (map[interface{}]interface{}) edit/add some values then convert it to JSON string and put it to PostgreSQL JSON column.

I tried this code to parse it but `content` seems to be null whereas `err` is false. `request.URL.Query()` prints a nice map object.

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(request.URL.Query())
i := v.Interface()
content, err := i.(map[interface{}]interface{})

// Do some operations

jsonString, _ := json.Marshal(content)

// Add to DB
```

Why is it null? Also am I thinking too generic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`content, err := i.(map[interface{}]interface{})`, this isn't a cast, it's a type assertion. You're saying (asserting) that interface is of type `map[interface{}]interface{}`, it's not. It's of type `map[string][]string`. You get `null` as the value because it fails. I highly doubt `error` is false.

Are you thinking too generic? Of course you are. I can't think of any reason why the collections type needs to change... Append what you want to it, write it to your db. There's nothing preventing that afaik?

Comment: What is the correct way to deal with JSON's which are really dynamic?

Comment: @Thellimist `map[string]interface{}` is probably the most popular way. Personally I've always avoided dynamic forms of unmarshalling. I'm pretty confident in saying no json is 'really dynamic'. There is always a schema, it just may be flexible. Reflection is never necessary in your code, only in the actual unmarshaller (in this case encoding/json but that same is true of other libraries in Go and other languages). Also, if the json is variant I can try `TypeA` then `B` then `C` to exhaust possible schemas, worst case I would do that. Get my errors out of the way up front.